# How does the glibc implementation of POSIX-AIO implement its thread pool?

Tags: linux, io, glibc

I am having trouble finding an explanation of POSIX-AIO's thread pool implementation in glibc -- all references to POSIX-AIO (in places such as the man page, keynotes, etc) all *mention* the thread pool but never its inner workings.

Using `strace` I have observed it relies heavily on calls to futex(), but I would like to know why this is the case.